# PHP str_replace "and"

Tags: php, str-replace

So I have str_replace which searches a string for "and" and replaces it with `&amp;`
However if there is a word which contains the letters "and" for example, "Howland" it will replace it with `Howl&amp;`.

How can I make it so that it only searches for the word and.

This is my function I have setup:

```
function add_ampersand( $string ) {
    $string = str_replace( 'and', '&amp;', $string );

    return $string;
}
```

I must note that this function is being used in a URL so the "and" will contain "-" next to either side of it, which then gets converted into spaces.

Comment: `str_replace( ' and ', '&amp;', $string )` ?

Comment: `str_replace( '-and-', ' &amp; ', $string)`

Comment: Actually I have the feeling you want to replace the single word `and` with `&`. That you then need a HTML entity for the `&` is written on a different sheet of paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
function add_ampersand( $string ) {
    $string = preg_replace( '/\band\b/', '&amp;', $string );

    return $string;
}
```

or

```
function add_ampersand( $string ) {
    $string = str_replace( ' and ', ' &amp; ', $string );

    return $string;
}
```

The first one is better in the case "and" is next to the end of the string or next to a special character such as `'`, `,` or `.`.

Comment: This did the trick, I had already tried adding the space before but I guess I forgot to add the space either side of the &amp; as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function add_ampersand( $string ) {
    $string = str_replace( ' and ', ' &amp; ', $string );
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you have strings like this: "-and" or "and-" or "-and-".
The easiest way of replacing it to &amp is this:

```
function add_ampersand( $string ) {
    $string = str_replace( '-and', '-&amp;', $string );
    $string = str_replace( 'and-', '&amp;-', $string );
    $string = str_replace( '-and-', '-&amp;-', $string );

    return $string;
}
```